# CF/SQL Check to see if date is past and if another field is completed

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I have two fields Date_Due and Date_Completed in my SQL database and I am trying to figure out how do a query to see if "todays date" is already past the Date_Due to see if it is overdue and if it is check to see if its already completed by seeing a date in the Date_Completed field? This is so that I can make a report of items that are overdue.

The first query is running fine but the second query is breaking at my WHERE statement. Any pointers on how to write this would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <cfquery name="received" datasource="officeweb">
        Select * 
        FROM dbo.Dealer_Track_Work 
        WHERE Date_Received between <cfqueryparam value="2015-10-13" /> 
        AND <cfqueryparam value="2015-10-26" /> 
</cfquery>

    <CFQUERY NAME="overdue" dbtype="query"> 
          Select *  
          from received     
          where CONVERT(date, getdate()) > Date_Due AND Date_Complete IS NULL
    </CFQUERY>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT *  
FROM received     
WHERE Date_Due > CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
  AND Date_Complete IS NULL
```

Comment: `date_due > CAST(DATE, GETDATE())`?

Comment: @vkp I don't like function in left side. This is just personal taste

Comment: yeah..but past today's date the op says.

Comment: @Vicki Try with `date_due > CAST(DATE, GETDATE())` and what do you mean by `breaks the page`?

Comment: @Vicki Could you share sample data and desired output

Comment: That returns records where the due date is in the future, not "overdue"  records (ie the due date has already passed). @Vicki - To avoid confusing future readers, could you please update your question to clarify the requirements?